# Today's Practicality of Bayesian Neural Networks

Tags: reference-request, applications, state-of-the-art, bayesian-deep-learning, bayesian-neural-networks

Just having heard lately about BNNs (wow, ANNs and CNNs are clear; now there's a B? What's that? Ahh, Bayesian ;-)) and quickly getting their main idea and focus, that is, **weights not** being pure static **numbers** anymore, but **instead** described by a **distribution function**, allowing the net to be "uncertain" about its answers (for more about BNNs, see, for example, [this post](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/26864/55856), or, if you want to know a lot about them, check out [this introduction and survey](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.12024.pdf)),

I'm now curious about any **practical examples** of where BNNs are used nowadays, maybe even more successful than other (deep learning) alternatives?

Thanks to [nbro](https://ai.stackexchange.com/users/2444/nbro)'s comment [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/34170/55856), pointing out that asking this question is not unknowingly, but relevant.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.00269.pdf

Comment: @Community I am questioning today's practicality of BNNs and asking (see tags) for state-of-the-art and/or references. I think it's clear what I am asking and how an adequate answer would look like. Please correct me if I am mistaken here.

Comment: @dangom I skimmed that article but I honestly could not find any real value about my question in it. It's morge like the introduction and survey I linked above; but not about its daily use.